# connecting SQL SERVER 2005 from Oracle

Tags: oracle

i am running Oracle and SQL SERVER 2oo5 on the same server.
Plstform  win 2003 Enterprise.
i have created a System file DSN.
Make the entry in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

but when i m tring to ping my dsn system dont responds. and when i m trying to create a database link using my dsn, it gives error.

What to do ?
thanks for help in advance.

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

-Create the UDL file

-Configure the heterogeneus services ($ORACLE_HOME\hs\admin) and create a file like `initDATAB.ora` with this content:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO="UDLFILE=C:\\ccc\\SQLSERVER.udl
```

-Add entry on `listener.ora` on `SID_LIST_LISTENER` like this:

```
   (SID_DESC=
      (SID_NAME=DATAB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM=hsolesql)
   )
```

-Create an entry on `tnsnames.ora`:

```
SQLSERVERDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = riereta)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME=DATAB)
    )
    (HS=OK) 
  )
```

-Create a database link pointing to `SQLSERVERDB`

**References**:

-[Oracle® Database Heterogeneous Connectivity Administrator's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/toc.htm)

-[Oracle® Database Net Services Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/toc.htm)

-[CREATE DATABASE LINK on Oracle® Database SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm#i2061505)